# Is a static variable in a library (DLL) shared by all processes referencing that library?

Tags: c#, dll, static, static-libraries, static-variables

I know that a static variable used in a web application is shared for all users across the web application. If I have a library (DLL) that uses some static private variable, do all applications using that library share the value of that variable?

For example, say I have the following code in my DLL:

```
private static bool isConnected = false;

public static void Connect()
{
    // TODO: Connect.
    isConnected = true;
}

public static void Disconnect()
{
    // TODO: Disconnect.
    isConnected = false;
}
```

Then in Application A, I call `myDLL.Connect()` which sets the value of `isConnected` to `True`. Then I have some Application B that does the same thing. If Application A later calls `myDLL.Disconnect()`, does Application B see `isConnected` as `False` because the two applications share the same DLL file with a static variable? The DLL file would, in this case, be literally the same file in the same file path.

(I previously asked a somewhat similar question about web applications [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899432/does-static-reference-to-httpcontext-current-session-return-same-session-for-all) It is not related.)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

No they won't. They are loaded in separate `AppDomains` and cannot see each other's instances.

Even if they refer to same physical file, each application gets its own *private instance* of the assembly.

Comment: does that mean if X application using the same DLL then there would be X instances of the assembly one for each APP? just confirming once.

Comment: Short answer - Yes. Long Answer: The keyword here is `AppDomain`. If there are `X AppDomains` then there would be `X` instances. By default, each App will have its own AppDomain which means for `X` Apps, there will be `X` instances. There are ways where you can load multiple apps in the same domain but that's a different discussion.