# Is Shared variable in library shared their value across all application that referring that library?

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, shared-memory, shared

This is possible duplicate. But, I couldn't able to find a prompt solution. Please help me out.

I have library project which has a class called `GetData(ByVal contextId as Integer)` function to get data from database and stores them into shared variable called `Public Shared _ContextData As String`. And, this library project referred by three window applications.

If all my three windows applications run simultaneously and try to get data with different `contextId` from database using the above method in that library.

Is there possible cause to share any one's `contextId` values across application?

I have referred below links already. But, they were telling the solution for web application.

[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6818052/is-a-static-variable-in-a-library-dll-shared-by-all-processes-referencing-that)

[Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4899432/does-static-reference-to-httpcontext-current-session-return-same-session-for-all)

Comment: Your Link 1 was *specifically* characterizing itself as *not* being about web application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shared` is only shared per application and ***not all*** applications, I'm afraid. When loading a DLL you load it into the application's memory, thus each application has its own instance of your library loaded into the application memory (which is why `Shared` doesn't work cross-application wise).

If you want to share data across many applications you should look into [**Memory Mapped Files**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

No, the `Shared` variables are bound to the ApplicationDomain (usually there is one per process). So in your case, you'd have a separate variable in memory for each process of your windows applications. If you run each of your windows applications, you'd have 3, if you run two instances of each of your windows applications, you'd have 6 separate variables.

If you would like to share the value across process boundaries, you'd have to look into cross process communication technologies like WCF or Named Pipes communication. Also, creating a service is an option.

A simpler option is to store the value in a database or in a file that each of the applications accesses. In either of these options, you'd need to think about how to handle concurrency situations when two applications access the value at the same time.

If the `contextId` does not change once it is selected, an option is to have a main application and choose the `contextId` in this application. You'd start the other applications from this main application (e.g. using `Process.Start`) and hand over the `contextId` as a command line argument. These "child"-applications use the `contextId` that is given to them at startup.